# how to execute a program in php using shell_exec()

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to compile python code using shell_exec(), or exec().
The code I am trying:

```php
$output = shell_exec("C:/Users/AS/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python.exe C:/wamp64/www/project/app/code.py 2>&1");
echo $output;
```

when I execute the command in shell or in the command line It works fine, However using php and (Apache sever) I get `The system cannot execute the specified program.` Though I can successfully execute different commands such as `mkdir`,
but if I try any  command with `.exe` extension in my windows 11, I get the the same error as above.

Comment: have you tried [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhfjQmtIvuE) ?